# Rails ignores if and else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**First thing, sorry for my bad english.**

I have a condition that put a string in a variable in my view.

My controller

```
    def  index
    @hosts= Host.all

    @hosts.each do |host|
      if host.ativo?
        @status = "Sim"
      else
        @status = "Não"
      end

      if Time.zone.now > host.validade
        flash[:info] = "Você tem hosts expirados !"
        @alerta = "Expirado !"
      else
        @alerta = "Válido !"
      end
     end
    end
```

My view

```
<tbody>
    <% @hosts.each do |host| %> 

      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to host.id, host_path(host),class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs'%></td>
        <td><%= host.mac %></td>
        <td><%= host.nome %></td>
        <td><%= host.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= @status %></td>
        <td><%= host.validade.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")%></td>
        <td><%= @alerta %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_host_path(host), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      host_path(host),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                      :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

But in my @alerta varibale i only get the string "Expirado" and in @status i only get "Sim" even if the @host.ativo? return false and Time.zone.now its < than host.validade

But if i put the same logic that is in controller in my view it works pretty well, i dont understand why

Answer (score 1):

Ruby most certainly doesn't ignore anything. Not on purpose. The problem is in your code. You run one loop in controller and **re-assign** the same two variables over and over again, for each host. So they will hold the values which were correct for the last cost.

Then you enumerate the hosts again, in the view. And just use those [wrongly] pre-calculated values.

The easiest fix here is to calculate those values directly in the view and ditch the loop in the controller.

A better thing to do would be to correctly prepare data for the view in controller. Now, several possibilities here. Either use "view models" (group a host with its view-specific data (status and alerta)) or use "presenters". Plenty of info in google by these keywords.

Comment: how did you know the variables are re-assigned ? condition could be one-shot or nothing condition

Comment: I just realized that all hosts are getting the strings of the last host i create, any idea about how i fix this ? i am really new in rails

Comment: in an if inside the loop, the if condition could happen to be true only for one iteration of the loop

Comment: @niceman: yet the variable is ovewritten regardless of condition's truthiness.

Comment: @LucasSantiago "any idea about how i fix this ?" - yes. the second part of the answer.

Comment: @LucasSantiago quick fix: move the condition into your view. Instead of `<td><%= @status %></td>` use `<td><% if host.ativo? %>Sim<% else %>Não<% end %></td>`

Comment: @Stefan i did this in, but some people told me that use this in view is not the best way.

Comment: @LucasSantiago: even I told you so. But it's the easiest way.